# Transform NavSatFix to Tf

Tags: ros, gps, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably a dumb question.

I am working with the Kitti dataset. I am trying to express the content of the topic /kitti/oxts/gps/fix (NavSatFix - lat, long, alt) in the reference world reference system of Tf (x, y, z).

Do you know a way to do it? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353407/transform-navsatfix-to-tf/) by [Filippo Grazioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/29827/filippo-grazioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2020-06-09**:
Hi @Filippo Grazioli,

Have you considered the [robot_localization](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html) package and its [navsat_transform_node](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/navsat_transform_node.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My personal solution was the following:

a) transform the initial GPS position (lat, long, alt) to an ECEF point - let's name this O;

b) center a ENU reference system in O;

c) express all other GPS positions (lat, long, alt) w.r.t. the ENU reference system centred in O.

---

Originally posted by [Filippo Grazioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/29827/filippo-grazioli/) with karma: 21 on 2020-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0